# how to find the version numbers of built in modules in php from the CLI

Tags: php, module, version

Basically i am new to php, and i just installed php on my machine.
so we can know entire information of the php configuration by creating a php file and
writing the below code in it

```
<?php 
  phpinfo();
?>
```

And i opened this through browser and can able to see all the configuration information

But is there any way to know the version of php default modules from linux terminal(I am using fedora by the way :) )

So what all i mean to ask is whether is there any way to find the version number of all the modules or individual modules from terminal through some php commands ?

For example there is a command `php -me` which displays all the php modules that comes by default when php is installed like below

```
[PHP modules]
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
....
.....
```

but in the same way i want to find the version number of the individual module too from the terminal, how can we find it ?

Comment: You can call phpinfo from the terminal with `php -i` and parse out the info you need.

Comment: And collect most of it with something like `$ php -i |grep -C4 -i version`

Comment: wow thats amazing i can see some output that i am waiting for when i used above command, but sorry i am new to use those and can u please let me know of finding single module version at a time like openssl from the command(:) :) because i had to do some functionality by finding the version number of individual module)

Comment: Try `php -i |grep -C4 -i "openssl.*version"`  The `-C4` provides 4 lines of context above and below, so you may get additional stuff in there you don't need.

Comment: Some modules report their version via `phpversion("modulename")` and you can therefore do `php -r "echo phpversion('modulename');"` from the CLI.  OpenSSL doesn't give output though...

Comment: I tried  php -r "echo phpversion('openssl');", but it failed silently

Comment: That seems to be because openssl doesn't report its version with phpversion(). If you tried it with `phpversion('mysql')` you would see output.

Comment: it is displaying 1.0 , actually what i was trying to do is looping through the result of "php -me" command and finding the version of each and every module by executin some command on it to find the version number of that particular module directly ?.

Comment: Use Gerald's answer below `foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $extension) echo "$extension: " . phpversion($extension) . "\n";` in a `php -r`and you'll get what you need.

Comment: yeah but as we have seen some of the modules are not getting the version number right ? but with php -i | grep command i can able to find the information for sure, but i need to fetch the required information from each result i think so ...

Comment: Yes you'll have a lot of manual parsing to do with `php -i |grep`. Several modules can't report their versions in `phpversion()`

Comment: yeah thats what i am bothered about..

Answer (score 46):

To see the version for one particular module, you can use the command `php --ri <module> | grep Version`.

For example:

`php --ri mongo | grep Version`

Returns:

```
Version => 1.6.5
```

Answer (score 29):

This should do the trick:

```
php -r 'foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $extension) echo "$extension: " . phpversion($extension) . "\n";'
```

More readable version (for code usage):

```
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions();
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    echo "$extension: " . phpversion($extension) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The OP wants this from the CLI, so wrap it in a call to `php -r`

Comment: Here I'll do it for you.  `php -r 'foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $extension) echo "$extension: " . phpversion($extension) . "\n";'`

Comment: if you use it in a PHP page, you may like `"<br />"` in place of `"\n"`

Answer (score 1):

you want the phpversion() command if you want to do it inscript
http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php